# Return only one row of a column for minimum time in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is a bit of a complicated question to ask, but I am sure someone here will know the answer in about 2 minutes and I'll feel stupid.

What I have is a table of routes, delivery names, and delivery times. Let's say it looks like this:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+
| ROUTE CODE |     NAME      | TIME  |
+------------+---------------+-------+
| A          | McDonald's    | 5:30  |
| A          | Arby's        | 5:45  |
| A          | Burger King   | 6:00  |
| A          | Wendy's       | 6:30  |
| B          | Arby's        | 7:45  |
| B          | Arby's        | 7:45  |
| B          | Burger King   | 8:30  |
| B          | McDonald's    | 9:00  |
| C          | Wendy's       | 9:30  |
| C          | Lion's Choice | 8:15  |
| C          | Steak N Shake | 9:50  |
| C          | Hardee's      | 10:30 |
+------------+---------------+-------+
```

What I want the result to return is something like this:

```
+------------+---------------+------+
| ROUTE CODE |     NAME      | TIME |
+------------+---------------+------+
| A          | McDonald's    | 5:30 |
| B          | Arby's        | 7:45 |
| C          | Lion's Choice | 8:15 |
+------------+---------------+------+
```

So what I want is the name of the minimum time for each route code.

I have written a query that gets me most of the way there (and feel free to improve upon this query if you think there is a more efficient way to do it):

```
SELECT main1.route_code, main1.first_stop, main2.name
FROM
  (SELECT route_code, min(time) as first_stop FROM table1 WHERE date = yesterday GROUP BY route_code) main1 
  JOIN 
  (SELECT route_code, name, time FROM table1 WHERE date = yesterday) main2 
  ON main1.route_code = main2.route_code and main1.first_stop = main2.time
```

Here is where I need your help though. If I have identical times, it returns that row twice, and I only want it once. So for instance, the above query would return Arby's for route code "B" twice because it has the same time. I only want to see that once, I never want to see anything from a route more than once.

Can anyone help me? Thanks much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (route_code) t.*
from table1 t
order by route_code, time asc;
```

This is likely to be the fastest method in Postgres.  For performance, an index on `(route_code, time)` is recommended.

Comment: Perfect. I did not know of the "distinct on" feature in Postgres. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to get your result that you may or may not like better:

```
SELECT route_name, time, name FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY route_code ORDER BY time ASC) row_num FROM table1) subq
WHERE row_num = 1;
```